# MKMapView location won't update

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit

After posting on Apple's iOS Devs forums with no answer, I'm trying to see if anyone's got any experience with such issue.
I'm using xcode for iOS 7.

MapView won't update. I'm quite sure the problem's within the simulator, though I'm not sure how to check it. I'd love to take this project on a real device but my iOS 7 device's still in store.

I created a MKMapView nested under a View (nested under a ViewController) -> Added CoreLocation and MapKit into Frameworks -> Connected the MKMapView to the right property mapView.

My files look like this:

**MapScanViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>    
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapScanViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>

// I was trying to create a label and print the 
// userLocation description into the label - but none worked
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

And **MapScanViewController.m** :

```
#import "MapScanViewController.h"

@implementation MapScanViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad    
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _mapView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);

    [_mapView setRegion:[_mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    // Label idea did not work eiter
    [_myLabel setText:[userLocation description]];    
}

@end
```

When I try to change location to Apple's Infinite loop, the map stays still like nothing's changing at all. Also tried to use bicycle ride and running but nothing happened. 
I tried to reset the iOS Simulator few times which did not help at all and of course tried to manually set the location from within xcode it-self.

Tried to add/force this (which did not help either):

```
if (_mapView.showsUserLocation)
{
_mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
_mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}
```

None worked for me. MapView just wont respond.

---

I verified the map view

```
// Meters-Miles convertion
#define METERS_PER_MILE 1609.344

// Just wanted to check if MapView's dead or not - worked- it took me to see (39.28..., -76.58...)
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // 1
    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = 39.281516;
    zoomLocation.longitude= -76.580806;

    // 2
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);

    // 3
    [_mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: edited to make it more readable. removed unrelated code

Comment: try adding `_mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;` in viewDidLoad No Ifs around it

Comment: Daji-Djan - This solved my issue! After adding this to viewDidLoad, iPhone prompted for location authorisation request. Once allowed, location is updated. Can you please post it as an answer so I'll be able to mark as solved? :) Thanks

Comment: done :) glad I cloud help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to call `_mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;` before you get anything from the map.

That call will for prompt the user for access to location services.

Answer (score 0):

As Daij-Djan said Try like  this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad    
{
 _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}
```

Comment: I want to update the location of MKMapView from other class. Lets say in my case: When I select a value in tableview, I assign the latitude & longitude to MapView in other class. Tried several ways like protocol & accessing the map view through class instance object. Nothing is working. Please help me, thanks :)

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya try creating a region, setting your desired location as it's centre and then `[mapView setRegion: newRegionWithDesiredCenter]` ?

Comment: @Hedgie Even that's not working, I tried several combinations of assigning span & coordinate values, assigning only location as you suggested, setting region that fits region with MKCoordinateRegion etc.  :(

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya submit a question with your code and reference a comment to that question so I can try helping :)

Comment: @Hedgie Posted the requirement on SO & [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644267/unable-to-change-mkmapview-regionlocation) is the link. Please help me, thanks :)